# What is the best way to reference users in a MVC model?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Let's say i want to build a commenting system for my ASP.NET MVC website. In my `Comment` model, I want to keep a reference to the users that liked or disliked a particular comment.

My model right now is:

```
public class Comment
{
    public int CommentId { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    // Problem lies here
    public virtual ICollection<?> LikedUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<?> DislikedUsers { get; set; }
}
```

## Question:

**What is the best way to reference those users?**

Things that come to my mind are :

- Store a list of UserIds that liked/disliked that comments as in:

  `public virtual ICollection<int> LikedUserIds { get; set; }`
- Reference those users directly but the problem here is that i don't know which type should i use for my `ICollection` to reference users in MVC directly. I'd like to know if users in ASP.NET Identity has a certain datatype so i can use here?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to store here is a typical example of key-value pairs. The key is the user and the value is his rating of a comment. Note that I say rating rather than like/dislike, because that is what the abstract domain meaning is. If you chose to go with "stars" or "score" later and have 5 possible rating values, it will be easier to refactor.

Thus:

1. Use `Dictionary<User, Rating>` where `Rating` is an **enum** with your values (Like, Dislike).
2. Implement your own `User` domain object. ASP.NET gives you `IPrincipal` and it should be used for security purposes only. It's not a good domain representation for users. You can always map from the IPrincipal to your own User object, where it is appropriate (post login for example).

Comment: I see, this certainly looks they way it should be implemented. Regarding 1,  I'm using Code First approach. Is it okay to have a `Dictionary<>` in my model? Regarding 2, So there is not a predefined datatype for the users in ASP.NET? I'm using the default MVC Identity system for my account management. Can `ApplicationUser` datatype be used to reference a user?